# Minimum count of lines that goes through the given points

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, unordered-set

First, I have defined `operator==` for `Point2D` and specialized `struct hash<Point2D>` template class to be able to consider points non-unique if they are on the same line.

In the code below I generate 1000 random points all on the same line and check if they are equal and I get printed `is equal: 1` `1000` times, but then at the end, it is being printed 2. When I experiment with `hash` function and return any of the commented values, the size of the `unordered_set` becomes 1 (even when I return a const number in a hash function). So what is wrong with my hash function below?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <limits>
#include <functional>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <random>
using namespace std;


struct Point2D
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator==(const Point2D& other) const
    {
        return x * other.y == y * other.x;
    }
};

namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Point2D>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Point2D& k) const
        {
            // Compute individual hash values for first,
            // second and combine them using XOR
            // and bit shifting:
            return ((hash<int>()(k.x) ^ (hash<int>()(k.y) << 1)) >> 1);

            /*
            int i1 = k.x;
            int i2 = k.y;
            size_t ret = i1;
            ret *= 2654435761U;
            return ret ^ i2;
            */

            /*
            return 111;
            */
        }
    };

}

int solution(vector<Point2D> &A)
{
    unordered_set<Point2D> pointsOnTheSameLine;

    for (auto& point : A)
    {
        pointsOnTheSameLine.insert(point);
    }

    return static_cast<int>(pointsOnTheSameLine.size());
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;     // only used once to initialise (seed) engine
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(-10000, 10000); // guaranteed unbiased

    int x = 13;
    int y = 7;
    vector<Point2D> v; // { {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1} };
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        auto random_integer = uni(rng);
        const Point2D curr{x * random_integer, y * random_integer};
        v.push_back(curr);

        cout << "is equal: " << (Point2D{x, y} == curr) << endl;
    }



    cout << solution(v) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can hash function affect the result. It can affect the time my program runs, as there can be big or small amount of collision depending on the hash function, but my program should return the same result, right?

Comment: Your code does not print 2, it prints various random values in the 950+ range to me ([demo](https://ideone.com/iS9Qwv)).

Comment: Here I could get 951 https://onlinegdb.com/Bklm8o7coG

Comment: What value do you expect to get, though?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I expect to get `1`, as according the my `operator==` all the generated points are equal. Number of unique points (not lying on the same line) in this context. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expect to get `1`, as according the my `operator==` all the generated points are equal

Equality according to `==` is not enough for a hash container to consider all points equal: hash function must also return the same value for points that are considered equal. When hashes are different, unordered container would not even apply your `operator==` to the values being stored, which results in the results that you see.

One approach for achieving this is to compute the slope by dividing out `gcd`, and xor-ing the numerator with denominator:

```
int gcd (int a, int b){
    a = abs(a); b = abs(b);
    return (b==0) ? a : gcd(b, a%b);
}

std::size_t operator()(const Point2D& k) const {
    int g = gcd(k.x, k.y);
    int a = k.x/g, b = k.y/g;
    return a ^ b;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/iS9Qwv)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that some points that are equal (true for Point2D::operator==) produce different hashes in your code.

Equal points should produce same hashes.

Comment: True, as `unordered_set` will consider all points different (even if they are equal according to my `operator==`) if the hash  func returns different values for different points, right?